# How to randomize the manner in which certain actions are performed in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, random

If I have certain instructions in separate classes, how would I bring them up randomly?

For e.g., if one class plays an audio file and another class adds two numbers, I want to be able to randomize to bring up a random number or label that corresponds to each class.

What is the syntax I need to use to carry out the aforementioned in C#?

Comment: You could use a Timer with random interval values.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a List, where ISomeAudioPlayer defines a `Play` method. Use the `Random` class to generate a number between 0 and the number of different possibilities, then call your Play method on the object at that index in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Put your actions into an array or similar structure.  If you want a random action pick a random element from the array.  If you want all the actions performed once then shuffle the array and work through the shuffled array in order.